# google style guide script or tool

Tags: c++, google-style-guide

Is there a script or tool that changes a code's style to google style not completely at least partially (maybe just syntax formatting)? 
We are reusing some of our C++ legacy code which is not formatted by google style standards and even just formatting it syntactically would take a few hours for a developer.

For now, we wrote some regular expressions that search and replace some basic style

Thanks

Comment: why pick the most infamously bad c++ style guide in existence? you have bad advisers. get copy of andre and herb's c++ style book.

Comment: also there are lots of c++ prettyfiers, including the one bundled with code::blocks

Comment: third, regarding the "regex" tag, regex is often a sure way to multiply your problems

Comment: @Alf: hmmm.. I didn't know that google style had that reputation. I am just following what my team has been doing so I really can't change at this point. btw, are you referring to "Exceptional C++ Style"??

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm

Comment: well i strongly disagree with "84. Prefer algorithm calls to handwritten loops. 162 ", and also there is bad advice in there about using static_cast instead of reinterpret_cast. but otherwise it's reportedly very fine book. like, the best there is.

Comment: @Alf: funny coincidence, I was actually debating on that yesterday about calling a function that takes 2 arguments on every element of a vector. And I ended up using loop just because it's readable. But I do prefer algorithm calls to handwritten loops. Is there a specific reason why you disagree?

Comment: @blueskin: without C++0x support you may need to create a predicate, the logic of the predicate is then far from its call site, unfortunately. `BOOST_FOREACH` is a good remedy for now, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/), however as you said this only does "syntax formatting":

> Artistic Style is a source code indenter, formatter, and beautifier for the C, C++, C# and Java programming languages.